# Delete The image from the folder in php

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote one php script in which i wrote the query for delete the particular selected image from my database. now i want to delete all the image which are from deleted from database and  also want to delete the image from my folder.
here i attach the pic of my database

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "cribsuite";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
//Query for delete the images from database 
$sql = "delete t1
from rr2s4_cma_images t1 JOIN rr2s4_cma_images t2
on t1.matrix_unique_id = t2.matrix_unique_id
and t1.ordering > t2.ordering";
//echo $sql;
$vin = mysql_query($sql);
//echo $sql;
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

[image]

Comment: you can use php `unlink` function to remove image from your folder

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `unlink(file_with_path)`

If you want to delete specific images which are already deleted from database, then you need to fetch images list from database using `SQL`.

You also need to fetch the images from folder using `glob`. Then compare the images and delete the images which are not in the image list from database

Comment: What i do if i want to delete particuler selected image from my folder which are deleted from database.

Comment: You need to know the file name before deleting it. This can be fetched from database. Another thing you can do is get all images list from database and get all images from folder. Delete all images from folder i.e. `unlink` which are not in database

Comment: "DELETE FROM rr2s4_cma_images WHERE matrix_unique_id='$matrix[$i]'"; i write these query or delete the data from table now i want to remain only one data which have minimum id than wt i do in these query?In these query first select distinct data from database and after that i delete the data but it delete all data from database.

Comment: Pass on your DELETE query. You need to select distinct images from database. loop them in PHP. You need to get all images using glob. Loop them and check if data is present in database. If not found then delete